# how to create a udev rule for usb flash with two partitions to create persistent node under /dev?

Tags: usb, mount, udev

I have a USB flash memory, I created two partitions on it, when it is attached sometimes it takes sda , sda1 and sda4 instead of sdb, sdb1, sdb4. To prevent that confusion I decided to create a udev rule to symlink it under /dev persistently.

I created the below rule

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0461", ATTRS{idProduct}=="4d81", SYMLINK+="myusb"
```

When I reboot it creates symlink under `/dev/myusb` but I can not mount it.

```
 sudo mount /dev/myusb /media/myusb

 mount: /dev/bus/usb/002/003 is not a block device
```

I think I get that error because  it contains two partitions.
So what shoul I do?

Comment: That's what UUIDs and labels are for...

Comment: @fkraiem
I  need to know if my  udev rule for two partitioned usb is ok, or do I need to add extra parameters for each partition.  I think the udev rule is ok, but I don't know how to distinguish each partition under `/dev/myusb`

Comment: What you should do is use UUIDs or labels, not a udev rule.

Comment: @fkraiem I know how to use and where to use UUIDs, my point is to create persistent node for USB under `/dev/myusb`

Comment: Maybe usbmount would help? http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/134797/how-to-automatically-mount-an-usb-device-on-plugin-time-on-an-already-running-sy

Comment: @JosefScript Thank you for the link, it seems close to my needs but I need to know how to create `udev rule` to automount `usb stick` with partitioned. I am trying to change parameters, maybe I should use `scsi` instead of `usb` in `SUBSYSTEM=="usb"`

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem is that you cannot mount a whole drive with several partitions at once. You have to mount each partition for itself. 
Mounting means getting access to the filesystem, which can be very different on two different partitions. And how would you put two filesystems into one directory? You have to have at least two subdirectories like `/media/myusb/part1`.

That said we are back to UUIDs and labels.

You could create an udev rule triggering a script that mounts the two partitions by their uuid, like

```
#!/bin/bash

mount /dev/disk/by-uuid/xxxxx-xxxx-xxxxx-xxxxxx /media/myusb/part1
mount /dev/disk/by-uuid/yyyyy-yyyy-yyyyyy-yyyyy /media/myusb/part2
```

Alternatively you could place the partitions into /etc/fstab, and let udev do  a `mount -a`  .

Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a  device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices that works even if disks are added and removed.

Maybe you could try that:

For partition one:

```
KERNEL=="sd?1", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0461", ATTRS{idProduct}=="4d81", SYMLINK+="myusb1"
```

For partition two

```
KERNEL=="sd?4", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0461", ATTRS{idProduct}=="4d81", SYMLINK+="myusb2"
```

Not sure if it works, but you could give it a try.

https://oracle-base.com/articles/linux/udev-scsi-rules-configuration-in-oracle-linux
https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/udev/

Comment: I get aware that I can not mount multiple partitions under one mount point, you are right about it. Though your answer provides a logic I'd prefere simple one liner `udev rule`

Comment: Added a oneliner to my answer. Did it work?

Comment: No, unfortunately it didn't work. But I found the working rule. If I post it here as a comment no body will notice it, so I ll post mine as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

First of all I want to thank all who responded, they guided me on the right path.

At first  I checked out devices to locate usb stick

```
 fdisk -l 

Disk /dev/sda: 15.5 GB, 15512174592 bytes
234 heads, 12 sectors/track, 10789 cylinders, total 30297216 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00055ec3

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *       16128    30297215    15140544    c  W95 FAT32 (LBA)
/dev/sda4         2142880     5194399     1525760    0  Empty

Disk /dev/sdb: 120.0 GB, 120034123776 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 14593 cylinders, total 234441648 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000517fa

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb2   *        2048    40959079    20478516   83  Linux
/dev/sdb3        40959998   234436544    96738273+   5  Extended
/dev/sdb5        40960000    52956093     5998047   83  Linux
/dev/sdb6        52957184   221904895    84473856   83  Linux
/dev/sdb7       221906944   234436544     6264800+  83  Linux
```

My usb stick grabbed `sda` `sda1` and `sda4` (I haven't  found a way to assign sda to primary disk yet)

Then I did an `attribute-walk` to get related parameters with

```
udevadm info -a -p $(udevadm info -q path -n /dev/sda)
udevadm info -a -p $(udevadm info -q path -n /dev/sda1)
udevadm info -a -p $(udevadm info -q path -n /dev/sda4)
```

I used   `ATTRS{serial}` and  `ATTR{partition}==1`, `ATTR{partition}==2` as distinguishing IDs.

```
KERNEL=="sd*", ATTRS{serial}=="0019E06B5883CCA187BC2C59", ATTR{partition}=="1", SYMLINK+="usbdevices"
```

works for partition 1